# Intent of ListView onClick

Tags: java, listview, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

Hello i want to go to another activity when i click a element of a listview but i want to pass the data of that listview to the other activity. I have search but always crash when it goes to the other activity. If i print the string it works correct, here is my code

```
 listaEmpresas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Object x = arrayadapter.getItem(position);
            String titulo  = (String) x;
            Log.i("info", titulo);


            Intent i = new Intent(Display.this, MasInfo.class);
            i.putExtra("titulo", x.toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

And in the other side i have

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mas_info);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String titulo = bundle.getString("titulo");
}
```

here is the error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: juanjoserodrigo.chilereclama, PID: 22293
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{juanjoserodrigo.chilereclama/juanjoserodrigo.chilereclama.MasInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2371)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5537)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                                              at juanjoserodrigo.chilereclama.MasInfo.<init>(MasInfo.java:15)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1070)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5537) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace to your error?

Comment: dont know what is that

Comment: It is the error message shown when the app crashes (found in the android monitor).

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Can you please add the whole stack trace (all the red text) to your post above. This can better help us diagnose your problem

Comment: ready i added above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no, this is different

Answer (score 0):

Since the getItem returns an int, your error is probably telling you that you cannot cast an integer to string. That should be your problem.

Comment: im not converting a int to string im getting the value of the list view and send it to the other activity

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?